# How many gaussian integers have modulus 5?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My work so far: $$0+5i\quad 5+0i\\ 3+4i\quad 4+3i$$
so there are 4 such integers. But when I type it in Brilliant I get wrong!! Maybe for them 0 is not an integer so I type 2 and I get wrong! What the heck is happening here? Are there more?

Comment: What about -5, 3-4i, -4+3i, ... ?

Answer (score 2):

The real and imaginary parts can also be negative ;-)

Comment: Aren't integers just elements of $\mathbb N$

Comment: The integers are all of the natural numbers, zero, and negatives of the natural numbers.

Comment: didn't know that!! anyway thanks!